# CMSMS does not display html code in edito

Tags: cmsmadesimple

I have a very weird problem with CMSMS. I have some HTML in my header file, there should be 2 links, but every time I paste a second one and click Apply- it disappears from editor. Although it shows on website.

CMSMS version: 1.11.9

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="logo_wrapper">
<div class="logo"><a href="{root_url}/"><img src="{root_url}/ui/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="span6 pull-right">{if $sid == 1 }
<div class="kabinet pull-right"><a class="rounded" href="apps/customer/web/profile/edit"> Профиль</a></div>
{else}
<div class="kabinet pull-right"><a class="rounded dark" href="#"> Статус доставки</a>       <a class="rounded" href="apps/customer/web/login"> Личный кабинет</a></div>
{/if}</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
<div class="nav">
<div class="nav-inner">{menu loadprops=0}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It should be after save:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="logo_wrapper">
<div class="logo"><a href="{root_url}/"><img src="{root_url}/ui/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="span6 pull-right">{if $sid == 1 }
<div class="kabinet pull-right"><a class="rounded" href="apps/customer/web/profile/edit"> Профиль</a>

(this link keeps disappearing)
<a class="rounded no-bg-color" href="apps/customer/web/logout"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i></a>

</div>
{else}
<div class="kabinet pull-right"><a class="rounded dark" href="#"> Статус доставки</a>       <a class="rounded" href="apps/customer/web/login"> Личный кабинет</a></div>
{/if}</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
<div class="nav">
<div class="nav-inner">{menu loadprops=0}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the HTML editor (MicroTiny I expect) believing that link is invalid HTML and throwing it away.

Set the editor to HTML mode so that you can edit the HTML directly (not WYSIWYG).  It will then accept your edits and not try to edit them.